# Mockito test for postForEntity not working

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I am trying to mock this method with postForEntity call -

```
public AuthorizeClient(RestTemplateBuilder builder, Config config) {
    this.grantedUrl = config.grantedUrl();
    this.restTemplate = HttpClientHelper.getRestTemplate(builder, authorizationConfig);
  }

private final RestTemplate restTemplate;
private String grantedUrl;
public List<Permission> getPermissions(
          PermissionsRequest permissionsRequest) {
    try {
      var headers = new HttpHeaders();
      var request = new HttpEntity<PermissionsRequest>(permissionsRequest, headers);
      var permissions = restTemplate.postForEntity(grantedUrl, request, Permission[].class);
      return Arrays.asList(permissions.getBody());
    } catch (HttpClientErrorException err) {
      logger.error(err);
      throw err;
    }
  }
```

Here is my test case -

```
RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder =  new RestTemplateBuilder();

Config config = new Config();

@InjectMocks
AuthorizeClient authorizeClient = new AuthorizeClient(restTemplateBuilder, config);

@Mock
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

PermissionsRequest permissionsRequest;

ResponseEntity<Permission[]> expGrantedPermissions;

@Test
    public void testAuthorizationPermissions()  {

        when(restTemplate.postForEntity(anyString(), any(), eq(Permission[].class))).thenReturn(expGrantedPermissions);

        var res = authorizeClient.getAllGrantedPermissions(permissionsRequest);
        assertNotNull(res);

    }
```

I'm getting this error since url is not mocked properly -

```
[ERROR] testAuthorizationPermissions  Time elapsed: 0.86 s  <<< ERROR!
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://localhost/v1/permissions": Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

Now I'm getting this error. Looks like mock is still not observed..

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute
```

At this line -

var res = authorizeClient.getPermissions(permissionsRequest);

My AuthorizeClient is constructed like above..

Please suggest what am I missing. Frankly no clue :(

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the `RestTemplate` is mocked, it doesn't take effect because the mock doesn't reach the tested object and the method `authorizeClient::getAllGrantedPermissions` uses its own implementation of `RestTemplate`.

The `RestTemplate` to be mocked must be also injected to the implementation which is supposed to use it, otherwise, the original, real, implementation is still used. Make the `RestTemplate` injectable:

```
class AuthorizeClient {                                 // You haven't specified the class name

    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;
    private String grantedUrl;

    public AuthorizeClient(RestTemplate restTemplate) { // Dependency injection through constructor
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

    public List<Permission> getPermissions(..) { .. }
}
```

And add [`@InjectMocks`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.2.0/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html) annotation to the tested object which should use mocked dependencies:

```
@Mock
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@InjectMock                                            // Injects all necessary @Mock objects
private AuthorizeClient authorizeClient;               // An implementation, not an interface

@Test
public void testAuthorizationPermissions()  {

    Mockito.when(restTemplate.postForEntity(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.any()))
           .thenReturn(expGrantedPermissions);

    // now it is assured the authorizeClient uses restTemplate and not its own one

    var res = authorizeClient.getAllGrantedPermissions(permissionsRequest);
    assertNotNull(res);

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Nikolas. This helped. I updated my question with some more info.

Comment: Rather ask a new question for a new issue raised. This question has been answered. Please, either accept the answer or edit the question to get a better one from me or anyone else - don't chain questions in a single one and keep them atomic. I believe you will more likely find an answer with asking a new question and move on, if this issue has been resolved :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I opened a new question.